# print letters and their ascii codes

Tags: c

i try to print all the letter from A to Z and from a to z and their ascii codes but i end up with an infinite loop when i am trying to run it ,so where is the mistake ?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
 int i;
 char ch_1,ch_2;

 for (ch_1='A'; ch_1<='Z'; ch_1++) printf("letter: %c ASCII code:%d\n",ch_1,ch_1);
 for (ch_2='a'; ch_1<='z'; ch_2++) printf("letter: %c ASCII code: %d\n",ch_2,ch_2);
}
```

Comment: While I do not know C, the one thing I see bothering me is this: `for (ch_2='a'; ch_1<='z'; ch_2++)`. Shouldn't it be `ch_2<='z';` instead of `ch_1<='z';`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
for (ch_2='a'; ch_2<='z'; ch_2++)
```

and not

```
for (ch_2='a'; ch_1<='z'; ch_2++)
```

Comment: hhahahaha didnt notice ...:) ok then

Answer (score 4):

In the 2nd for line, your end-of-sequence function is wrong. It says:

```
ch_1<='z'
```

and it should say:

```
ch_2<='z'
```

A common mistake!

Answer (score 2):

your mistake is in the second for loop condition. your wrote ch_1 instead of ch_2.